# Number of pixels declared for SizedBox's width & height not universal across multiple devices

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's an example of declaring the height & width of a SizedBox:

`SizedBox(width: 40, height: 40)`

In some cases (on other devices), I've noticed that sometimes the dimensions get overflowed and causes errors. In my mind, I thought that declaring by pixel number would be universal across all devices because 200 pixels should be 200 pixels regardless of device screen size. But clearly I was wrong, so is there a quick or easy way to fix my error to make sure the width/height stays universal across all devices?

The problem with using MediaQuery.of(context).size.width is that in some instances whenever you have a wide screen or when the user tilts the phone in landscape view, using MediaQuery would make the width or height way too long & would not pass the esthetic test.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Not all devices have the same amount of pixels

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `FractionallySizedBox` to set a percentage of the width/height that should be taken from all screens:

```
FractionallySizedBox(
  heightFactor: 0.2, // will take 20% of the screen height.
  widthFactor: 0.4, // will take 40% of the screen width.
);
```

Comment: Thank you but this would act similarly to MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.4 which is what I want to avoid doing because the app can also be viewed in landscape mode and whenever the width of the screen is wider then portrait mode, it makes the SizedBox look too wide and doesn't fit the esthetic look needed for my specific purpose.

Comment: oh and you want to set a consition for each screen size manually ?

Comment: I could but looking to see if there would be a more reliable/easier method to achieve the same purpose

Comment: you can use a LayoutBuilder ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a condition for each screen size but avoid messy code. You should try to do it with an extension.

For example:

```
extension BoxWithSizes on double {
   
   double get conditional {
        return (//size of screen < 600) ? this : this - 30;
   }

}
```

And use it like

```
SizedBox(width: 30.conditional)
```

The thing with this is that you should do like in CSS, a different getter extension for differents components